# Chrome inspector issue while remote debugging

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, developer-tools, inspector

I am trying to debug my android web application which I had written by Ionic framework and AngularJS and is rendered on webview browser on android platform by chrome://inspect#devices but I am seeing this screen:
[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGv0m.png)

it was working perfectly for last 5 months but now it is killing me.
I tried uninstalling chrome, reset settings, reset dev.tools but they were not practical solutions.
In addition, it is working fine while inspecting a regular website on google chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should try to test it with a fresh ionic app, and you will see if it's problem of your app or chrome.

In case that it's chrome problem, try to open an emulator and inspect it, maybe it's Android problem or USB error.